# How to inject RequestScoped bean into Axis2 POJO web service?

Tags: cdi, apache-axis, inject

We are currently building a web application where the backend is exposing the server functionality via REST web services (using Jersey). However, there is one web service which needs to be a SOAP service due to backwards compatibility. We have for this implemented a POJO (generated as Axis2 web service using Eclipse to get the setup right) which we deploy as an Axis2 web service on a Tomcat. The SOAP web service is defined as request scoped (done in **services.xml**). Calling this web service, using both Kerberos and NTLM for authentication (which one depends on the environment where the web app is deployed) works fine.

Now, we want to reuse some of the functionality of the REST services. The REST services are only used as facades and the business logic are implemented in **@RequestScoped** beans being injected into the REST services using CDI and **@Inject**. It would be perfect if we could inject a @RequestScoped bean into our POJO but this doesn't seem to work. The bean to be injected also have dependencies on other @RequestScoped beans which are also injected using CDI. Basically, it will cause an entire tree of object dependencies to be instanciated.

Now, my question is if this scenario should in general be possible, i.e. injecting a @RequestScoped bean into an Axis2 POJO using CDI? If not, do you have any suggestions of how this could be solved in a different manner, i.e. reusing @RequestScoped beans in an Axis2 POJO?

Here are some code samples of our setup:

**POJO:**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;

public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private MyRequestScopedService mrss;

    public MyResponse getSomeData(MyRequest myRequest) {
        // some logic...
    }
}
```

**Bean to inject:**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@RequestScoped
public class MyRequestScopedService {

    @Inject
    private MyOtherRequestScopedService morss;

    [...]  // a few other beans are also injected

    public SomeData getSomeData(SomeRequest someRequest) {
        // some logic...
    }

    [...]
}
```

**services.xml**

```
<service name="MyService" scope="request">
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.domain.MyService</parameter>
</service>
```

If you need some more details, please let me know.